# Media queries - targeting specific devices together

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile, mobile-safari, media-queries

I've got a devices stylesheet that is loaded to deal with responsive design in a website, but I'm struggling to group a couple different media queries exactly how I want.

I've got a shared set of styles for a small web window, a mobile device at any rotation and an iPad in portrait only.

At the moment I'm getting everything except the iPad with this query:

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px), all and (max-width: 480px)
```

I'm getting the iPad in portrait with this code:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
```

How do I combine these two media queries?

Comment: Can you give an example? or suggest why? Mobile/smart-phones and tablets are different devices. iPads can also be problematic to match as different generations have different screen resolutions.

Comment: Short answer: client requirements.

Basically they want their mobile site for phones and the full site looks good and functions well on an iPad in landscape, but not portrait, so they want the mobile site version on the portrait view.

Is it not possible to combine a query with both of these variables? At the moment my temporary work around is completely duplicating the styles which is stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for anyone with this problem.

To achieve this I ended up using the media queries to load the stylesheet, rather than embedding the media query in my stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px), all and (max-width: 480px)" href="device.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)" href="device.css" />
```